# How to replace elements of vectors based on pipe operator

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe

Let's say I have below vector

```
Vec = c("AA", "BB1", "CC2")
```

Now I want to replace few specific elements based on pattern match as follows

```
Vec[grepl("[0-9]+$", Vec)] <- paste("CCC", grep("[0-9]+$", Vec, value = T))
Vec
## [1] "AA"      "CCC BB1" "CCC CC2"
```

How can I execute above step using `pipe` operator? Below is my try

```
library(dplyr)

Vec = c("AA", "BB1", "CC2")
Vec %>% `<-`(.[grepl("[0-9]+$", .)], paste("CCC", grep("[0-9]+$", ., value = T)))
```

With that, I am getting below error

```
Error in Vec %>% (.[grepl("[0-9]+$", .)] <- paste("CCC", grep("[0-9]+$",  : 
  incorrect number of arguments to "<-"
```

What is the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `grepl` result is of length 2 while your `Vec` is of length 3, that's why incorrect number of arguments. So in a `{}` we can do the `grepl` stuff, but to give back the entire vector we need another `.` which is a separate code line achieved with `;`.

```
library(dplyr)
Vec = c("AA", "BB1", "CC2")
Vec %>% {`<-`(.[grepl("[0-9]+$", .)], paste("CCC", grep("[0-9]+$", ., value = T)));.}
# [1] "AA"      "CCC BB1" "CCC CC2"
```

Alternatively you could use `replace`.

```
Vec %>% replace(grepl("[0-9]+$", .), paste("CCC", grep("[0-9]+$", ., value=TRUE)))
# [1] "AA"      "CCC BB1" "CCC CC2"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `str_replace`:

```
Vec %>%
     str_replace('(.*[0-9]+)$', 'CCC \\1')
```